# refresh a page after upgrade react and next latest version got re-hydration error ?give any possible way to fix this issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

```
            <div>
                <p>
                    Gender : <span >{gender}</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Age : <span>{age} Yrs</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Question: <span>{question}</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </>
replace a paragraph tag inside div but is doesn't work for me
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You seem to have accidentally removed all the information which made the existing answer possible. I undid that. Please have a looks at [ask] and the concept of making a [mre]. Maybe for what you attempted to improve, this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Where do `gender`, `age`, and `question` come from? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

replace h elements inside div

```
<div>
    <h2>John Deo</h2>                         
    <p>Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative thinkingorporate strategy foster collaborative thinking</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).